# Detect when an exception is thrown and handled in an inner function

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception, python-sphinx

I'm having trouble trying to figure out how to check when an exception is raised when building with sphinx. I have the following line of code:

```
    sphinx.build_main(['-b html', source_dir, target_dir])
```

the function `build_main` main would throw errors if certain parts of a build weren't correct, however the exceptions are **caught and handled** internally meaning I can't explicitly try-catch them. As as example the output of the function `build_main` is

```
Running Sphinx v1.3.1
loading translations [Python]... not available for built-in messages
loading pickled environment... done
building [mo]: targets for 0 po files that are out of date
building [html]: targets for 0 source files that are out of date
updating environment: 0 added, 1 changed, 0 removed
reading sources... [100%] test
C:\Users\fakeuser\Documents\Github\travis-sphinx\test\docs\source\test.rst:7: WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module u'test.t
his'; the following exception was raised:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\grant mercer\anaconda\lib\site-packages\sphinx-1.3.1-py2.7.egg\sphinx\ext\autodoc.py", line 385, in import_object
    __import__(self.modname)
ImportError: No module named this
looking for now-outdated files... none found
pickling environment... done
checking consistency... done
preparing documents... done
writing output... [100%] test
generating indices... genindex
writing additional pages... search
copying static files... done
copying extra files... done
dumping search index in English (code: en) ... done
dumping object inventory... done
build succeeded, 1 warning.
```

I purposely created this error with the intent of catching stuff like this, but I can't figure out how. Is there anyway to detect when an exception is thrown in an inner function even if it's caught and handled before I can use it? I tried

```
try:
    sphinx.build_main(['-b html', source_dir, target_dir])
except:
    print 'exception!'
```

but nothing is caught (as expected)